# move folder from dbfs location to user workspace directory in azure databricks

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to move group of files(python or scala file from)or folder from dbfs location to user workspace directory to do testing on file.

Its verify difficult to upload each file one by one into the user workspace directory, so is it possible to move file from dbfs location to user workspace directory in azure databricks.

Since i am not able to upload folder instead of file directly or huge than some particular size, could you suggest the way to move or copy files into user workspace directory in azure databricks.

Answer (score 0):

### You can upload folder in any Azure cloud storage resources using the *Azure Storage Explorer* application from Microsoft

. You can download the application [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/#overview).
After you have downloaded the application, you can sign in your Azure account and select the storage you want folder to upload to.

Please see this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#connect-to-a-storage-account-or-service) from Microsoft for connecting the azure account tot storage explorer and [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs#get-the-sas-for-a-blob-container) to upload folder using the Azure Storage Explorer.

### References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs#get-the-sas-for-a-blob-container

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows

Comment: For uploading folder from storage account into user workspace directory, we don't have shared access signature.

how do I find delta location for user workspace directory and how do I move file from storage account into that user workspace location?

Comment: Does the user is part of your Azure Active Directory? If so, you can login in azure storage using the users credential and can view and upload the folder in the user workspace directory. Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows) for more details.